# Show that T a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the vector space consisting of all 2x2 matrices and let C be a fixed 2x2 matrix. Let T:V →V be a function given by the formula T(A)=CA for a matrix A in V. Show that T a linear transformation.

Note: Here, we don't know what the matrix C is. But it does not matter. Please do NOT give an example of the matrix C. Simply use the known properties of matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a scalar in the field $K$, where the vector space of all $2\times 2$ matrices is over the field $K$, and let $A_1,A_2,C$ denote matrices in the vector space of all $2\times 2$ matrices, where $C$ is the given $2\times 2$ matrix. Then,
$$T:A_1+A_2\to C(A_1+A_2)=CA_1+CA_2$$
Since matrix multiplication is distributive. Also,
$$T:\alpha A_1\to C(\alpha A_1)$$
Since $\alpha \in K$, $C\alpha=\alpha C$, and hence, $C(\alpha A_1)=\alpha CA_1$. Q.E.D.

Comment: @user131057 Sure!

Comment: @user131057 Please do read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer. If this answer was what you wanted, click on the green check mark next to the answer to mark this question as answered.